# WCF and out parameters

Tags: wcf

It seems there is restriction in having the number of out parameters in WCF. My service reference only downloads one out parameter.

Example: if the service has the following method:

```
void methodA(out string param1, out string param2)
```

then the service reference will only create

```
methodA(out string param1).
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent an out-parameter to end up return parameter in a WCF web service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294971/how-can-i-prevent-an-out-parameter-to-end-up-return-parameter-in-a-wcf-web-servi) : The other question is better and has a better answer than this one, even though this one is older.

Answer (score 8):

I don't believe there's a limit to the number of out-parameters.

However, for a method that returns `void`, the first out-parameter actually becomes the return value of the method in the service reference due to a limitation in WSDL. So I would expect the signature of the method to become `string methodA(out string param2)`.

Comment: have u tried it? coz i've tried it and it returns string methodA(out string param1)

Comment: Yes, in my case the signature was as described; first out-parameter became the return value, second out-parameter became the first parameter as so on. In your case it also returns string. Have you tested the actual output of the return value and the out-parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of a correct fix, but I would return a list of items and not use out parameters in this situation.

Comment: yeah.. that could be one solution. for time being it is working fine for "ref" parameter. What a shame that WCF limits only one out parameter.

Comment: we had two out params in our asmx service so i believe its not wsdl