# Contract failure when accessing a function in Web service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I am fairly new to `C#` and `web services`...

I have added, in my web service, a contract of this sort :

```
void SomeFunc(string someString, out List<string> someList);
```

I have a feeling something might be wrong with this - I want a list to be returned from the service - though I know List is passed by reference, but not sure how it'll work for web service interaction.

So, 1. could someone please tell me if the above is a correct implementation,

and..

In my client, the same function appears to take a string parameter, but returns instead a string array.

The signature changes to :

```
string[] someFunc(string);
```

So something missing here already.

When I do declare a string array and try to receive the values, I get a Contract Mismatch exception.

Where could the fix be?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294971/how-can-i-prevent-an-out-parameter-to-end-up-return-parameter-in-a-wcf-web-servi.

Comment: Thank you. I shall take a look.